# Append new data into an existing frame and upload to sheets Python

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm connected to my APIs client, sent the credentials, I made the request, I asked the API for data and put it to a DF.

Then, I have to upload this data to a sheet, so then this sheet is gonna be connected to PowerBI as a datasource in order to develop a dashboard and monitor some KPIs and so on..

**Simple and common ETL process. BUT: to be honest, I'm a rookie and I'm doing my best.**

Above here is just code to connect to the API, here is where the **"extraction"** begins

```
if response_page.status_code == 200:
    if page == 1 :
        df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(response_page.content)["list"])
    else :
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(response_page.content)["list"])
        
        df = df.append(df2)
```

**Then I just pick up but I need:**

```
columnas = ['orderId','totalValue','paymentNames']
df2 = df[columnas]
df2
```

This is what the DF looks like:

[example: this df is which I need to append the new data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KABAG.png)

Then I've just connected to Sheets here, send the credentials, open the sheet("carrefourMetodosDePago") and the page("transacciones")

```
sa = gspread.service_account(filename="service_account.json")
sh = sa.open("carrefourMetodosDePago")
wks = sh.worksheet("transacciones")
```

**The magic begins:**

```
wks.update([df2.columns.values.tolist()] + df2.values.tolist())
```

With this sentence I upload what the picture shows, to the sheet!

**I need the new data that generates the API to be appended/merged/concatenated to the current data so the code upload the current data PLUS the new everytime I run it and so forth.**

**How can I do that? Should I use a for loop and iterate over every new data en append it to the sheet?**

This is the best I could have done, I think I reached my turning point here...

If I explained myself wrong just let me know.
If you reach up to here just let me **thank you** to give me some time :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I could not find a question in there.

Comment: @Cooper I've just edit it, thanks for your comment!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images?

Comment: Do you speak spanish? french? @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, my mother language is Japanese. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: 履歴データを含むdfに新しいデータを挿入する必要があります @Tanaike

Comment: Hi I believe you should take a look a the documentation of `gspread` regarding the method `worksheet.update`. if you don't provide a range in the arguments then it will update the sheet starting from cell A1. See [here](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.3.2/api.html#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.update)